# Changing Bootstrap Theme with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This should be pretty simple. I am trying to change bootstraps theme from default to a dark theme with the following code and javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/static/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Dynamic theme updates -->
<script>
    var themes = {
        "default": "",
        "inverse" : "/static/darktheme.css"
    }

    function changeTheme(themeType) {
        var themeurl = themes[themeType]; 
        document.getElementById("mynavbar").className = "navbar navbar-" + themeType + " navbar-fixed-top";

        var themeRef = document.getElementById("theme-ref")
        themeRef.setAttribute("href", themeurl)
    };
</script>

<link id="theme-ref" rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

And here is my navbar with the button to change it:

```
 <div id="mynavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
          <img style="max-width: 70px;" src="static/me-logo.png">
            C&T Tool
          </a>


          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
               an item here
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><another item</li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Theme<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" data-theme="default" onclick="changeTheme('default')" class="theme-link">Light</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-theme="inverse"    onclick="changeTheme('inverse')" class="theme-link">Dark</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            {% block navsubmit %}
            {% endblock %}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

It works but I have to click it twice to get it to work fully. The first click on inverse changes the font and some margins and the second click on inverse changes the colors and everything else. What could make this happen? I'm using [this theme](http://bootswatch.com/darkly/).

Comment: Made a Plunker for it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3IFN00b6kySY2Ku6yYsb?p=preview but colors seem to change on first click.

Comment: Actually that is strange, it was because I was using the minified version of the darktheme.css. When I used the normal version, and the one in the Plunker, it works just fine. I wouldn't have expected that but thanks for the help.